# How to create a simple, in-text table in RMarkdown that works with PDF output

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, tabular

everybody!

I usually output .RMarkdown as html file and use the following to create an in-text table.

```
variable|Description
--------|-----------
`var1`  |abcdefg
`var2`  |gfedcba
```

But it doesn't apply to pdf output. Because I want to keep variable names as `var1`, I prefer not to use code chunk to generate the table. I also tried Latex syntax and something I found online (e.g. below). However, none of these approaches works.

```
variable  Description
--------  --------------
`var1`    abcdefg
`var2`    gfedcba
--------  --------------

|variable|Description|
|:-------|----------:|
|`var1`  |abcdefg    |
|`var2`  |gfedcba    |
```

It shouldn't be this twisted. Does anybody have a simple solution to this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack  that can solve your problem. Export the file as HTML format (as it works fine in this way), open the file on browser and `print[CTRL+P]` and `save as pdf`.

Comment: Oh, I did try that already. This is for a course report, and if I upload a pdf converted from html via the system, it becomes unreadable immediately.